# Unable to run pip3 - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Python3.7.1. I am trying to run pip3, but I get an error with the lsb_release program:

```
$ pip3 -V

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distro'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  ...
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 932, in _get_lsb_release_info
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I don't see what's wrong, the file starts with the right header:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es
```

I can see pip3 is actually there:

```
$ whereis pip3
pip3: /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip3, but nothing changed.

**EDIT:**

This solved my problem:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1003535/619372

Comment: try `whereis pip` then show the output is is there any `pip3`

Comment: Robin, install `lsb-release` and see. `lsb-release - Linux Standard Base version reporting utility`. I wouldn't have thought `pip` would fail on that :). `pip._vendor.distro` checks the `distro` info using `lsb_release` command (from the `traceback`)which is provided by `lsb-release` package in `debian` family

Comment: I have the newest version of lsb-release :
"lsb-release is already the newest version"

Comment: uninstall pip3 and try installing it